# Excel: Structured Table Reference doesn't get updated after Excel File is saved

Tags: excel, excel-tables

I have a simple Excel Table, named "Beta0" with two Columns "Date" and " Value". "Beta0" is created (and most importantly also updated) via a PowerQuery from a web page and is located in "Sheet1". The Power Query works all fine and updates the Table every Day, as it should. I now want to refer to the column "Value" from another sheet ("Sheet2") which also works:

```
"random_cell_in_sheet2" =Beta0[Value]
```

Excel then duplicates the whole column "Value" from "Sheet1" to "Sheet2" and more importantly, it updates the column in "Sheet2" when I update the "twin"-Column in "Sheet1". Dark magic kicks in, when i save the whole file. After reopening the file, the Code from above ist transferred from:

```
"random_cell_in_sheet2" = Beta0[Value]
```

to

```
"random_cell_in_sheet2" {=Sheet1!A3:A5881}
```

This Code will not update anything that I type in the "Value" from "Sheet1".

Is there something wrong with my Settings, that it doesn't save my my Structured Table Reference in the first Place? Can you please help me?

Comment: Try using Indirect to lock the reference as a literal string.

Comment: doesnt work either. =INDIREKT(C6 & "[" & D6 & "]") after saving gets compiled to: {=INDIREKT(C6 & "[" & D6 & "]")} which doesnt update automatically

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! Was using an very old sheet (originated in the 1996s!). After updating the sheet, everything worked as it should :)